# Where to Find MP (U.K.) Allowances?

Tags: data-request

I'm trying to find the *breakdown* allowances of Members of Parliament of the United Kingdom, but I've been unsuccessful so far.

For instance, Scottish Parliament releases this data in great detail on [their website](http://mspallowances.scottish.parliament.uk/) which allows you to see *each* expenditure claimed by each MSP and some other details too.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is available from the [Independent Parliamentary Standards Authority](http://www.theipsa.org.uk/), although their website seems to be down at the moment.

[MPs’ Expenses.info](https://www.mpsexpenses.info/) republishes the information in a format that is quite similar to that used by the Scottish Parliament. As an example, you can see claims made by [Jacob Rees-Mogg](https://www.mpsexpenses.info/#!/mp/576). Note the date selector at the top of the page that allows you to see claims for previous years back to 2010.

Comment: Is the data provided by IPSA machine-readable (or “parsable” by any means)? I’m asking since mpsexpenses.info provides already-processed data it seems. Lastly, do you know how long has IPSA’s website been down (as I’m afraid they might not fix it anytime soon, effectively omitting information)? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Their website is back up now. There doesn't seem to be an API but you can download CSVs for individual MPs by [selecting an MP from their list](http://www.theipsa.org.uk/mp-costs/your-mp/), selecting 'Individual claims' and 'Download'. It might help to ask the people behind MP's Expenses.info if/how they're scraping the data.